# how do i install a control that came as a dll

Tags: c#

I just downloaded a control that I want to add to Visual C# .NET, it came as a .dll file.

How do I install this?

(Visual C# Express 2008)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the top menu: `Tools`, `Choose Toolbox Items...`, click `Browse...` and find your DLL. That will install it onto the toolbox for all projects.

If you want to use the control in only one project, add the DLL as a regular reference to the project.

Comment: Yea, it's pretty sad when so many problems with `choose toolbox items` are present that when you start typing `choose toolbox` google auto-types it for `items crash`. I've tried everything I could find short of a reinstall and that little option still causes VS to crash

Comment: +1 for the solution. @Dave I recommend you to mark this as answer since it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a reference from your project to the new dll.